# TYPO3 RTE wraps address-elements in p-elements and outputs invalid HTML

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I have a content element in *TYPO3 6.2.4*. This content element contains multiple `<address>`-elements, like:

```
<address>An address</address>
<address>Some phone numbers and emails</address>
```

The problem is the output, as it looks like this, even if I remove all whitespaces:

```
<p class="bodytext">
    <address>An address</address>
</p>
<p class="bodytext">
    <address>Some phone numbers and emails</address>
</p>
```

This is not only bad, but it is also invalid markup.

I tried the following but it unfortunately removes **all** `<p>`-elements even the correct ones:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.nonWrappedTag >
```

This is how I get the content into the template:

```
lib.content < styles.content.get
```

This is how it is outputted:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content" />
```

And this is in my RTE configuration:

```
RTE.default {
    proc {
        allowTags = h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div, p, br, span, ul, ol, li, blockquote, footer, strong, em, b, i, u, a, img, hr, q, cite, abbr, acronym, center, address

        exitHTMLparser_db = 1
        exitHTMLparser_db {
            tags.b.remap = strong
            tags.i.remap = em
        }
    }
}

RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside:= addToList(address)
```

How can I get rid of those wrapping `<p>`-elements?

Comment: I'd like to contribute to your question but from the snippet posted it looks as you would do everything right. Maybe some configuration is not applied. Could you add the complete RTE configuration (from Info -> PageTSconfig) here?